# abstract class and generics in Scala

Tags: scala

i am trying to move my existing app written in java to scala,but i am struggling against
this particular one,.
In java, i have the following abstract class :

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao<T, ID extends Serializable> extends
    HibernateDaoSupport implements GenericDao<T, ID> {

     private final Class<? extends T> persistentClass;

     public AbstractHibernateDao(Class<? extends T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
     }
```

I am trying to write that in Scala, but i am struggling with the variable persistentClass, which is of type Class

i have tried the following but it fails big time

```
abstract class ScalaHibernateDao[T, ID <: Serializable](persistentClass <: T) extends
    HibernateDaoSupport with GenericDao[T, ID] {
```

could anyone assist pls?

w/kindest regards
 Marco

Comment: val persistentClass: Class[T]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the specification `Class[_ <: T]` here to match the Java style:

```
abstract class ScalaHibernateDao[T, ID <: Serializable](persistentClass: Class[_ <: T]) extends HibernateDaoSupport with GenericDao[T, ID] { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive the following is idiomatic Scala approach:

```
abstract class ScalaHibernateDao[T: ClassTag, ID <: Serializable] extends HibernateDaoSupport with GenericDao[T, ID] {
  private val persistentClass = classTag[T].runtimeClass
}
```

When using `ClassTag`s you won't have to pass `Class[_]` instance manually, the compiler will do it for you:

```
class SomeEntityDao extends ScalaHibernateDao[SomeEntity, Long]
```

`Class[SomeEntity]` then will be automatically resolved.